# get meta tags and img tags contents from an iframe source using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meta-tags

I have an HTML file with the following content

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>builder 1.0</title>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="a.html" name="cxsideframe" scrolling:'no';="" id="frame1" style="overflow:hidden;">
</iframe>
</body></html>
```

The content of a.html is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>builder v1.0</title>

<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

<meta content="desc goes here" name="description">
<meta content="auth name" name="author">
<body>
<img src="http://example.com/images/01._V397411194_.png" style="display:none" alt=""/>
<img src="http://example.com/images/V386942464_.gif" style="display:none" alt="" />
</body></html>
```

I need to extract the contents of meta tags and image lists of a.html from the parent page using jQuery or javascript.

I tried

```
alert($('#frame1').contents().find($('#meta[name=description]').attr("content")).html());


and 
$('meta[name=author]').attr("content");
```

But did not got the solution.Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of attribute `content` Use

```
alert($('#frame1').contents().find('meta[name=description]').attr("content"));
```

and to get all the images as array

```
$('#frame1').contents().find('img')
```

**EDIT :** Make sure that you are calling these methods after the iframe content has been loaded.
So use

```
$("#frame1").ready(function(){
alert($('#frame1').contents().find('meta[name=description]').attr("content"));
alert($('#frame1').contents().find('img'));
})
```

Comment: I get blank array when I console this

Comment: which browser you are using

Comment: chromium 18 and firefox 12

Comment: the issue may be somewhere else in your code because it works

Answer (score -1):

for example place a button and on button get content of iframe

```
function getContentFromIframe(){
    var myIFrame=document.getElementById('iframe');
    var content=myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
```